# Command-line call for compiling C++ on Visual C++ compiler, with assembler included?

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2010

Could someone please tell me, if I were to compile a C++ file from C#, what would the execution string be (assuming I am using x86 cl.exe for compiling). I would like to output the assembler along with original source code (similar to the option in Visual Studio)?

Something like (just example):

> " cl.exe   my_cpp_file.cpp -assembler -source_code"

and would it be much different for compiling C?

EDIT is this correct? I need to use "FAs"

CL FAs my_cpp_file.cpp

I'm not too sure what to do about? ... [lib...] [@command-file] [/link link-opt...]

(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/610ecb4h(v=vs.100).aspx)

I would also like to do full-optimization compiling

EDIT2 I dont want to execute the file, all I wish to do is produce the assembler output (with source code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `/FAs` option seems to be what you're looking for.  Check out the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/367y26c6%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Comment: The problem is they dont give an actual example, just lots of generic template symbols. I just need to see an example

Comment: There's an example right there on that page under the 'example' heading:  `CL /FAcs HELLO.CPP`